# two barplots in one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have two working barplots about the sentiments of tweets (neutral, positive, negative). How can I merge them into one, side by side?

First bar:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6,5))
plt.title('Classification of All tweets into sentiment categories',fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Percentage [%]',fontsize=18)
ax = (df_navalny.sentiment.value_counts()/len(df_navalny)*100).plot(kind="bar", rot=0,color=['#04407F','#0656AC','#0A73E1'])
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 110, 10))
plt.grid(color='#95a5a6', linestyle='-.', linewidth=1, axis='y', alpha=0.7)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 110, 10)*len(df_navalny)/100)
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate('{:.2f}%'.format(p.get_height()), (p.get_x()+0.15, p.get_height()+1))
```

Second bar:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6,5))
plt.title('Classification of All tweets into sentiment categories',fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Percentage [%]',fontsize=18)
ax = (df_putin.sentiment.value_counts()/len(df_putin)*100).plot(kind="bar", rot=0,color=['#04407F','#0656AC','#0A73E1'])
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 110, 10))
plt.grid(color='#95a5a6', linestyle='-.', linewidth=1, axis='y', alpha=0.7)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 110, 10)*len(df_putin)/100)
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate('{:.2f}%'.format(p.get_height()), (p.get_x()+0.15, p.get_height()+1))
```

Comment: Have you tried using subplots? https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

Comment: Can you specify how you want to merge them? https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html

Comment: @pask as a grouped bar chart with labels, yes, but I cannot make work my code on this example

Comment: fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
Define first plot with ax1 and the second with ax2.

Comment: This question is not reproducible without **data**. This question needs a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How to provide a reproducible dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52413246/7758804), then **[edit] your question**, and paste the clipboard into a code block. Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay. If you don't include an mre, it is likely the question will be downvoted, closed, and deleted.

Comment: This requires an example of `df_navalny` and `df_putin` to add a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit complicated but Matplotlib site offers a [demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axisartist/demo_parasite_axes2.html#sphx-glr-gallery-axisartist-demo-parasite-axes2-py) and when you copy and past you have the following

[image]
Here it is the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
from mpl_toolkits import axisartist

# fake data
a = [2341, 5670, 4822]
b = [4290, 5205, 3966]
pca, pcb = [[round(100*x/sum(l),2) for x in l] for l in (a, b)]

# prepare all the vertical axes
ax = host_subplot(111, axes_class=axisartist.Axes)
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.67)
axa = ax.twinx() ; axb = ax.twinx()
axb.axis['right'] = axb.new_fixed_axis(loc="right", offset=(60, 0))
axa.axis['right'].toggle(all=True)
axb.axis['right'].toggle(all=True)

# plot the bars PLUS invisible lines to represent the samples numerosities
x, w = np.array((1,2,3)), 0.30
ax.bar(x-w, pca, width=w, align='edge', label='a', zorder=1)
ax.bar(x-0, pcb, width=w, align='edge', label='b', zorder=1)
axa.plot((1,1),(0,sum(a)),lw=0)
axb.plot((1,1),(0,sum(b)),lw=0)

# fix xtics, xlabels, 'regular' yticks
plt.xticks((1,2,3)) ; ax.set_xticklabels('NO == YES'.split())
ax.set_yticks(range(0, 101, 10))

# all the ylabels
ax.set_ylabel('Percentages')
axa.set_ylabel('Numerosity of a')
axb.set_ylabel('Numerosity of b')
axa.set_ylim(bottom=0.0)
axb.set_ylim(bottom=0.0)
plt.legend()
plt.grid(zorder=0)
plt.show()
```